# Require one group of inputs or another

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that has a group of inputs for gathering SSN (3 fields) and another group for gathering EIN (2 fields). How can I make it so that either the SSN fields OR the EIN fields are required but not both of them?

```
<input name="ssn_1" type="text" class="ssn" value="" style="width: 7.3%; height: 3.2%; top: 37.8%; left: 68.1%;" maxlength="3">
<input name="ssn_2" type="text" class="ssn" value="" style="width: 4.9%; height: 3.2%; top: 37.8%; left: 77.6%;" maxlength="2">
<input name="ssn_3" type="text" class="ssn" value="" style="width: 9.5%; height: 3.2%; top: 37.8%; left: 84.7%;" maxlength="4">
<input name="ein_1" type="text" class="ein" value="" style="width: 4.9%; height: 3.2%; top: 43.9%; left: 68.1%;" maxlength="2">
<input name="ein_2" type="text" class="ein" value="" style="width: 16.7%; height: 3.2%; top: 43.9%; left: 75.1%;" maxlength="7">
```

Thank you and please let me know if you have questions or need further information

Comment: Are we assuming you're using the jQuery Validate plugin only because you've used the [tag:jquery-validate] tag?  If so, please show the relevant jQuery code like your call to the `.validate()` method.

Comment: Sorry, yes I am using the jQuery Validate plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions here...

**1)  Simple solution:**  Combine the SSN into a single input field as a nine digit number and handle the data formatting on the back end just before you write to the database.  Do the same with the EIN field.  Then you can use the `require_from_group` method to automatically make EIN OR SSN required.  IMO, this is easier on the user (and more modern GUI) to simply enter nine digits all at once rather than tabbing between multiple fields.  After all, for example, you hardly see three fields for entering phone numbers on any site, and almost never on the newest sites.

HTML:

```
<input name="ssn" type="text" class="mygroup" />
<input name="ein" type="text" class="mygroup" />
```

`.validate()` Rules:

```
rules: {
    ssn: {
        digits: true,         // <- numbers only
        rangelength: [9,9],   // <- force exactly 9 characters
        require_from_group: [2, '.mygroup'] // <- SSN OR EIN is required, not both
    },
    ein: {
        digits: true,       
        rangelength: [9,9], 
        require_from_group: [2, '.mygroup'] // <- SSN OR EIN is required, not both
    }
}
```

I'd also set the `digits` and `rangelength` rules to force a nine digit number on the field, rather than a simple `maxlength` attribute in the HTML.

---

**2)  More complex solution:**  Otherwise, keeping your five fields, use an event like `blur` or `change` to trigger [the `.rules()` methods](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/).  Use `.rules('add')` to add rules to a field and `.rules('remove')` to remove all rules on a field.  For example, if the user is filling out the SSN fields, you can dynamically remove the `required` rules from the EIN fields.  There is one trick here:  if your selector targets more than one element, you must use a jQuery `.each()`.

Examples:

```
$('#oneField').rules('add', {  // <- single element in selector
    required: true
});

$('.manyFields').each(function() {  // <- multiple elements in selector
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have the option of combining the fields. My life would be easier if I could do that :)